# Continue after one try failed In try catch in swift

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch

I have a try block like below. When one try failes, It goes to catch block but I want it to run second and third try blocks too. A solution would be putting all tries in different try catch blocks but I'm wondering If there is a better solution?

```
do{
    try AppURLCache.instance.fetchList()
    try ParamCache.instance.fetchList()
    try AnalyticsManager.instance.initGoogleAnalyticsManager()
} catch let error as ServiceError {
    print(error.message)
} catch let error{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Posible Solution:

```
do{
    try AppURLCache.instance.fetchList()
} catch let error as ServiceError {
    print(error.message)
} catch let error{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
do{
    try ParamCache.instance.fetchList()
} catch let error as ServiceError {
    print(error.message)
} catch let error{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
do{
    try AnalyticsManager.instance.initGoogleAnalyticsManager()
} catch let error as ServiceError {
    print(error.message)
} catch let error{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you get exception, it will go to catch block, you can't change that. If you use try?, then you can do this but won't be able to catch the exception which will defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try?` instead of `try`:

**try?**

If we use the `try?` keyword and an error is thrown, the error is handled by turning it into an optional value. This means that there is no need to wrap the throwing method call in a `do-catch` statement, So that you will not able to catch the error.

```
try? AppURLCache.instance.fetchList()
try? ParamCache.instance.fetchList()
try? AnalyticsManager.instance.initGoogleAnalyticsManager()
```